# What is the correct/classic way to report the CCR in a research paper?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, pattern-recognition

I am working on a feature extraction scheme and finally I need to report the correct classification rate (CCR) in a table with confusion matrix. I made a Monte Carlo iteration procedure to see the result of CCR for our algorithm (means with different set of cross validation). In fact, there is no big tolerance among all the iterations but there is `1.5%` difference between the average of all CCR in Monte Carlo and the maximum CCR. My question is:

- As I want to provide the confusion table, what should I report for the confusion table: the one related to maximum of CCR in Monte Carlo iterations or the one related to the average of the CCR for all iterations?

Notice that, for average case, one difficulty is that the confusion table should be based on numbers of each class not in percentage, so when I take average, then there would be some decimal numbers however those should be Natural numbers. I asked this question because in our reference papers nobody talked about the Monte Carlo iterations and I guess their result is the maximum one.

- **Summary of the question by @Lucas:** "If I understood you correctly, you ran a cross-validation to measure CCR with different training and test sets and are now wondering whether to take the average or the maximum of these values?"

Comment: What is ACC? If I understood you correctly, you ran a cross-validation to measure CCR with different training and test sets and are now wondering whether to take the average or the maximum of these values? I didn't get your point about natural numbers.

Comment: @Lucas: I edited. I mean the positive integers should be in confusion table as the number of correct recognition not in percentage format. I think your thinking is the case that I asked. I asked this because in our reference papers nobody talked about that.